# Curious to know how to change the color of a substring and leave the rest of the color of the text the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to be able to change a particular substring [!] to the color red and the rest would be the same text color black.  I know the logic must be implemented in this portion of my code.

```
render() {
  var substring = "[!]"
  return(
    <div>
      <h2>Render</h2>
      <div id="render" class="render"> {this.state.loading || !this.state.data ? < div id="render"></div> :
      <div>{this.state.data.toString().replace(/•/g, " ")}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you want to style part of a string, use a `span` element.

Comment: This is what the `SPAN` tag is for

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  So something like this:   <div>{this.state.data.toString().replace(/•/g, " ")}<span style="color:red;">{substring}</span></div>

Comment: That would only work if the span was always at the end of the string. Better to introduce the <span> as part of the replacement, instead of an empty string.

Comment: You can use a function as a replace statement